# GridSearchCV for MLPClassifier does not return best_estimator_

Tags: scikit-learn

I use `GridSearchCV` to tune the `MLPClassifier` parameters:

```
def fit(self, X, y):
    param_grid = {
        'hidden_layer_sizes': [(7, 7), (128,), (128, 7)],
        'tol': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6],
        'epsilon': [1e-3, 1e-7, 1e-8, 1e-9, 1e-8]
    }
    self.estimator = GridSearchCV(
        MLPClassifier(learning_rate='adaptive', learning_rate_init=1., early_stopping=True, shuffle=True),
        param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
    self.estimator.fit(X, y)
    self.estimator = self.estimator.best_estimator_
    print self.estimator.best_estimator_
    return self
```

By using `print self.estimator.best_estimator_`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'
```

I am not able to get what parameters are chosen for the resulted model. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
self.estimator = self.estimator.best_estimator_
```

you are taking the best-estimator (MLPClassifier) and store it into variable `self.estimator`, **overwriting** your original variable `self.estimator`

But then:

```
self.estimator.best_estimator_
```

is wrong, as `self.estimator` is already the best estimator, but it has no attribute named like that. You did lose one layer due to your operation before!

This is indicated by the error `AttributeError: 'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'`, which tells you, that `self.estimator` is an object of type MLPClassifier, but not the typical GridSearchCV result-type.